# Is There a way to hide Javascript code in PHP files?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to keep my JavaScript code away from Code Theft It's too complicated to copyright and code Obfuscator could be undone I have seen people putting JavaScript code in PHP files.
`<script src="some.thing/js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>`
Is this an efficient way?
How is it done?

Comment: You cannot hide code that has to be sent to the client browser.

Comment: You can't hide. What you can do is to "minify" and "uglify" it to make hard to copy, but never hide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will not hide it at all.

The JavaScript might be *generated* by executing a PHP program, but the JS itself is still sent to the browser and has to be executed there.

A client can make an HTTP request to a URL ending in `.php` just as easily as it can to one ending in `.js`.